# smarty tpl file does not read the tpl file properly

Tags: html, css

I am new to smarty, so I am not sure if that is causing me to miss something but currently I am trying to pull a class from the css file.

So far I have setup 2 clases `mainbackground` and `body`, `mainbackground` is intended to just be a background color but it does not get any of the values i add to the css, while the `body` css details are given to the div in it.

Can anybody see if I did something wrong?

**CSS:**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
mainbackground{
    background-color:#000       
}

body{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:80%;
}
```

**HTML(tpl file):**

```
<link href="/templates/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
<div class="mainbackground">
    <div class="body">
        <div align="center">
            <img src="../images/Logo.jpg" width="279" height="215" longdesc="#" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS syntax is invalid. classes have to be prefixed with a dot:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.mainbackground{
    background-color:#000       
}

.body{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:80%;
}
```

without the dot, it will refer to the tag name.
ids will be refered to with a #sign

Comment: I seriously cannot believe I missed that... Thanks so much